# Change memory of integer?

Tags: c, integer

Can I change the memory of integer?
Example:

```
int x;// Reservation 2 or 4 bytes in memory.
```

Is it possible to change 2 bytes to 40 bytes, for example?
I am using C language.

Comment: I think you want `char x[40];` or `void* x = malloc(40);`.

Comment: Is to change the maximum representative value.
Int x; Can represent at most 2147483647 and then goes to the negative numbers. But I need to return a value greater than the representable by 2 bytes. The function returns an integer for example 21474836479936424623543224 and this number exceeds the number represented by 1 integer.

Comment: The largest signed number representable in two 8-bit bytes is 32767; to handle 2147483647 you need 32 bits (4 bytes).

Comment: you can try `long long`, these are "commonly" 8 bytes, but probably depends on your system. I haven't checked if that's big enough for the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest more or less standard integer representation is `long long`, which is generally 64 bits. If you absolutely need 64 bits, you should `#include <stdint.h>` and then use `int64_t` (or `uint64_t` for unsigned integers). That will get you numbers as big as 9223372036854775807 (signed) or 18446744073709551615 (unsigned).

If even that is insufficient to your needs, then you'll need a [multi-precision arithmetic library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change how many bytes the compiler allocates for an object when you use

```
int x;
```

If you want to allocate a certain number of bytes, use an array if the size is known at compile time.

```
char array[100];
```

If the size is known only at run time, use dynamically allocated memory.

```
char* array = malloc(array_size);
```

Comment: int x = 124552559 * 2355235235325; I need to write to the screen the integer of the variable x

Comment: @ManuelJose, you should look into an implementation of `bigint`. Ex: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libbigint/.

Answer (score 0):

How many bytes your machine allocates to each data type (including 'int') depends on your machine and on your operating system. If you would like to specify exactly how many bytes long it should be, try using the data types found in the stdint.h library, such as uint8_t or uint16_t, rather than 'int.'